# iOS Should I Use Core Data?

Tags: ios, core-data

I have an exercise application that allows you to create a Workout Program, and then create individual Workouts associated with the Program.  You can also create Workouts independent of any Program.  I'm new to Obj-C fundamentals and am trying to figure out how I should tie in Workouts with their Program (keeping in mind that eventually reporting data will use the relationship between the two).

I've concluded that this can/should be done in 1 of 2 ways and need help learning which is the most efficient:

1) When a Workout is created, see if it originates from a Program or is on it's own (this is how I've done it successfully now).  If it's from a program, add a 'WorkoutInProgram' Core Data attribute to the Workout which will store the ProgramName.  Then whenever I want to fetch all Workouts in a Program, I just look up the attribute where WorkoutInProgram == ProgramName.

2) Create some sort of Core Data relationship between Workouts and Programs.  When a Workout is created within a Program, the relationship between the ProgramName attribute (of the Program entity) and the Workout entity is stored.  I spent around an hour trying to figure out this relationship, got confused, and resorted to #1 which worked.

I'm not sure if a Core Data relationship is useful here, I got hung up on the fact that multiple Workouts would be associated with a single Program entity based on ProgramName.

As always, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is roughly what things should look like in XCode.  Program.workouts is a To-Many relationship and Workouts.program is an optional To-One relationship.

[image: Program Entity]
[image: Workout entity]

Generated NSManagedObject subclasses should look like this

```
//
//  Program.h
//  CoreDataLibraryApp
//
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@class Workout;

@interface Program : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate * timeStamp;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *workouts;
@end

@interface Program (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)

- (void)addWorkoutsObject:(Workout *)value;
- (void)removeWorkoutsObject:(Workout *)value;
- (void)addWorkouts:(NSSet *)values;
- (void)removeWorkouts:(NSSet *)values;

@end

//
//  Workout.h
//  CoreDataLibraryApp
//
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@class Program;

@interface Workout : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Program *program;

@end
```

When you create a new `Workout` you can set the `program` attribute like this:

```
  newWorkout.program = selectedProgram;
```

If you want to get all workouts for a program you do something like this

```
for (Workout *workout in selectedProgram.workouts) {
   NSLog(@" workout is %@", workout.name);
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks for taking the time!  Helped my understanding of CD, setting up that relationship was a lot easier than I thought.  One question regarding the methods you added like addWorkoutsObject, etc...

Is utilizing those just a shorter way of adding/removing a workout from a program?  Right now I'm able to add workouts to a program just by fetching the Program object by programName and then adding `newWorkout.program = selectedProgram` when I create a Workout...I'm not seeing where I'd use those methods.

Comment: Those subclasses and methods are automatically generated by xCode and I don't use them. Just use the = assignment.

Comment: To generate a subclass use File->New then select NSManagedSubclass and select the classes from you model.

Answer (score 0):

What you've done so far is create your own relationship manually, you just aren't using Core Data to manage the relationship.  I would recommend creating a one-to-many relationship between Program and Workout.  The relationship can be specified as optional so it doesn't have to be populated.

Some benefits to having the relationship specified with Core Data include automatically keeping things in sync if the name of the Program ever changes, being able to specify delete behaviors, and code simplification when it comes to fetching the Program associated with a Workout.

One thing that might be causing confusion (I know it did for me at first) is that you don't specify the relationships based on specific attributes (like you would if you were creating a model in a relational DB).  You don't, for example, create a specific attribute for the purpose of linking the two entities together.  Instead, when you create your relationship, you might name it "program" in the Workout entity and "workouts" in the Program entity.